# Object Parameter in Method Stub with Mockito

Tags: java, testing, spring-boot, mockito, stub

I'm trying to make a test on my restController in a Spring-Boot application.

The method i want to test is a crud method ( insert ) that rely on a service that rely on a MongoRepository.

I've done like below but i can't figure out why test isn't working, after many researches on web.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = ConfigTagController.class, secure = false)
public class ConfigTagControllerTest {

@Autowired
MockMvc mvc;

@MockBean
ConfigTagService service;


//dati mockati
private ConfigTagEntity mockTag = new ConfigTagEntity("test",new ArrayList<>());
private ConfigTagEntity mockTag1 = new ConfigTagEntity("test1",new ArrayList<>());
private Collection<ConfigTagEntity> mockTagCollection = Arrays.asList(mockTag,mockTag1);

//baseurl del controller
private String baseUrl = "/v1/configtag";

@Test
public void insertTest() throws Exception {

    //Jackson library
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    //Object to JSON in String
    String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(mockTag);

    //stub del metodo
    Mockito.when(service.insert(anyObject())).thenReturn(true);

    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(baseUrl);
    request.param(jsonInString);

    System.out.println(request);


    this.mvc.perform(request)
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
}
```

When i try to run the test i get this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'values' must not be empty

at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:228).......stacktrace
```

**this is the service method:**

```
public boolean insert(ConfigTagEntity entity) {
    if (configTagRepository.findByTagName(entity.getTagName()) == null) {
        /* ... */
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**this is the controller method**

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/configtag",method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Void> insert(@RequestBody ConfigTagEntity entity) {
    return checkCall(configTagService.insert(entity));
}
```

**edit
STACK TRACE**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'values' must not be empty

at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.addToMultiValueMap(MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.java:773)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.param(MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.java:329)
at com.pcsystem.controller.ConfigTagControllerTest.insertTest(ConfigTagControllerTest.java:114)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Where is `service` coming from? Could you add the stacktrace?

Comment: is inside the test class, sorry, stay tuned for edit -> EDIT DONE

Comment: I think the stacktrace is needed to find your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your json payload as a query param.

So instead of

```
request.param(jsonInString);
```

you should try

```
request.content(jsonInString);
```

Also you need to add the content-type header

```
request.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Comment: see now after edit, i've forgot to put the entire test class